# JavaMail, how to add an icon to the email subject?

Tags: jakarta-mail

I'm using JavaMail and Spring Boot. The site sends e-mail notifications to its users.
Is there any way to add an icon to the e-mail subject? So that the icon is shown in the list of messages next to the e-mail subject.

Answer (score 0):

No.

You can [include Unicode characters in the Subject](https://javaee.github.io/javamail/docs/api/javax/mail/internet/MimeMessage.html#setSubject-java.lang.String-java.lang.String-), which includes varies glyphs, but you can't include an arbitrary icon.

Comment: I've seen some icons which were definitely not unicode glyphs. Maybe they were not a part of a subject but something like file attachments (or, not exactly file attachments). So, we have a messages list, there are icons (like PNG favicons) near each item. What is it, how they are added there?

Comment: It completely depends on which mailer you're using.  Every mailer will be different.  Post a picture of the mailer you're using and the MIME content of a message that causes the icons to be displayed and maybe we can figure it out for that mailer.

Comment: It's a GMail account and JavaMail behind the scenes in our application. After some research, I think that this is not of a concern of JavaMail, it's user's setup in his/her GMail - or whatever mail service he/she is using - mail account.